# Why does API test issued by apiary fail to pass request.POST processing of Django?

Tags: django, api, apiary

It's the apiary's API doc

```
+ Request (application/json)

    {
        'name':"testUser",
        'password':"1234"

    }
```

When I click ”Call Resource“ on the right side,my django server get this request,but when i print(request.POST) and print(request.body) in django,it display:

```
<QueryDict: {}>
b'{\n    \'name\':"testUser",\n    \'password\':"1234"\n\n}'
```

when I use another APi test tools,django server display

```
<QueryDict: {'name': ['testUser'], 'password': ['1234']}>
b'name=testUser&password=1234'
```

Why does apiary have such a situation? What should I do so that I can use it correctly?

Comment: Your first test is sending JSON, the second is sending form-encoded data.

Comment: The JSON Body in the example isn't valid as JSON requires the keys to be wrapped in doule quotes `"` instead of single quotes like in Python (`'`). If you change the quotation of `name` and `password` keys in the JSON body Django should be able to parse it properly.

Comment: Thank you for pointing out my mistake, but when I modified it`+ Request (application/json)

        {
            "name":"testUser",
            "password":"1234"
            
        }` I also get this info in django `<QueryDict: {}>
b'{\n    "name":"testUser",\n    "password":"1234"\n\n}'`